# ggplot with data from two structures

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use R to plot corresponding data that lives in two different frames. In the end I should get a plot that shows n-lines of (x1 vs y1), (x2 vs y2), and so forth.

Below is my attempt as a MWE, but it doesn't plot all the lines and it's not elegant. Any suggestions on how to melt or gather to massage the data would be deeply appreciated.

```
X = data.frame(x1=c(1 , 2,3,4,5),
               x2=c(1 , 4,3,4,5),
               x3=c(14,12,3,4,5))

Y = data.frame(y1=c(1, 2, 3,4,5),
               y2=c(1, 2,10,4,5),
               y3=c(1,21,10,4,5))

a = cbind(X,Y)

gg<-ggplot(a)+
    geom_line(aes(x=a[,1] , y=a[,1+3], col = colors[1], lwd=1 ))

 for(i in 2:3){
     gg<- gg + 
     geom_line(aes(x=a[ ,i] ,y = a[,i+3], col = colors[i], lwd=1 ))
}

gg
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation of @Peter's approach

```
cbind(X,Y) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = c("col", "series"), names_pattern = "(.)(.)") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = series)) + 
  geom_path()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

a <-  
  cbind(X, Y) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("coord", "group"), sep = 1) %>%
  group_by(coord, group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         group = paste0("X", group, "-", "Y", group))%>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = coord, values_from = value) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(group, id)

ggplot(a) +
    geom_path(aes(x, y, colour = group, group = group), lwd = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**data**

```
X = data.frame(x1=c(1 , 2,3,4,5),
               x2=c(1 , 4,3,4,5),
               x3=c(14,12,3,4,5))

Y = data.frame(y1=c(1, 2, 3,4,5),
               y2=c(1, 2,10,4,5),
               y3=c(1,21,10,4,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as a reply since it's a bit long. You both got me 98% of the way there and I'm infinitely thankful. Here's the code that did it for me, taking from @Peter's answer:

```
a<-cbind(A,B) %>%
    pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
    separate(name, into = c("coord", "group"), sep = 1) %>%
    group_by(coord, group) %>% 
    mutate(id = row_number(),
           group = paste0("X", group, "-", "Y", group))%>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = coord, values_from = value) 

ggplot(a)+
  aes(x=x,y=y, color=group)+
  geom_line()
```

Comment: `geom_line` plots variables in order of the  x axis, whereas  `geom_path` plots  variables in data frame order. The question was not explicit about plotting order.